# Putting an ID on Element to easily Find Later

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a selenium test for a drag and drop table, wherein products from an item catalog are dragged to a container. You are able to drag multiple instances of one type of item and this is the cause of the hard part.

In this scenario, every item has a serial number. I can locate them via xpath, but all the instances would show up in my search.

My question is if there is a way for me to attach a unique identifier to each element I drag to the table, that way later, I can search them using that ID.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can execute javascript within selenium so you could attach a randomized string and apply it as an ID on a given element. Then you'd be able to just do `findElement(By.Id(<random string>));` However, this would only work if the page does not reload.

Comment: Monkeying with the page would really be an act of desperation. OP, are you sure there are no element properties / attributes you can check for? No other way you can distinguish them? What about the innerHtml? I assume you're in control of your test data...

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. To be honest, I'm not really well versed with Javascript and was hoping to go the full C# route. The ID was really the last resort, now I've sent the request for the UI team to add an ID to the element so I can easily look it up through the ID attribute, but that will take time as they have other priorities.

@AndrewRegan, yes I agree, it totally is an act of desperation, and I'm a little desperate right now. It's actually in SVG, there's no containers, just <rect>'s overlapping each other.

Comment: Also, these <rect>'s have no ID's or any unique identifier that I can lookup.  Being inexperienced, my first plan was to create an object for each item.

`var code = new Item();`

With the constructor creating a GuiD.NewGuid on the Item that I was planning to lookup later. But Alas, it doesn't work that way.